# Setting date format within a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching data from 3 different tables (using INNER JOIN) to create an HTML code that gives me a random portrait photo of a person and the persons birth- and deathdates (see the result here:  https://www.hafdal.dk/legstadaleit/ - below the headstone image).

This is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
    '<center><img src="https://www.hafdal.dk/tng/andlitsmyndir/',
    tng_media.path,'" alt="',
    tng_media.description,
    '" width="250"><br><a href="https://www.hafdal.dk/legstadaleit/index.php/database/?page=www.hafdal.dk/tng/getperson.php%3FpersonID%3D',
    tng_medialinks.personID,
    '"><b>',
    tng_media.description, 
    '</b><br>', 
    'f. ', 
    tng_people.birthdate, 
    ' - d. ', 
    tng_people.deathdate, 
    '</a></center>') 
FROM `tng_media`   
INNER JOIN tng_medialinks on tng_media.mediaID=tng_medialinks.mediaID  
INNER JOIN tng_people on tng_people.personID=tng_medialinks.personID   
WHERE mediatypeID="11"
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

How can I format the date so that it *looks* Icelandic, i.e. the month names are in Icelandic and there is a `.` after the date number and month name?  Like this:  `12. des. 2018`.

I have tried inserting:

```
DATE_FORMAT (tng_people.birthdate, '%d. %M %Y')
```

where `tng_people.birthdate` is, but that does not work, unfortunately.

Is is possible to change the date format, with the SQL query?  I have no possibilities of adding/changing the database, just pulling data from it.

The format of birthdate in the database is "dd MMM YYYYY" in English (varchar(50)).   I also have the possibility of using the variable birthdatetr which is "YYYY-MM-DD" (date).

I cannot change the overall language of the database because I also use it in Danish and English.  So I need to figure out how to do this

[image]

Comment: How does `birthdate` store in database? What type does this column have? Attach example of a value from this column to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql date format regarding to a specific country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500509/mysql-date-format-regarding-to-a-specific-country)

Comment: Is `tng_people.birthdate` a proper Date type ? Shouldn't the expected output be: `12. Dec. 2018` not `..des..`

Comment: [`<center>`](https://i.imgflip.com/2orvsl.jpg)

Comment: I have added information regarding type to my question.  Have to admit I hadn't noticed that the birthdate variable was varchar :´/  So perhaps my problem is that I should use birthdatetr instead??

Answer (score 1):

From `Date_Format()` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

> The language used for day and month names and abbreviations is
>   controlled by the value of the `lc_time_names` system variable

For Iceland, the locale value is `is_IS`. Check full list at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html

You will need to set the system variable before calling the query:

```
SET SESSION lc_time_names = 'is_IS';
```

Also, your `Date_format()` specifier string needs to be changed to:

```
DATE_FORMAT (tng_people.birthdate, '%d. %b. %Y')
```

[**Details**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

- `%d`     Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
- `%b`     Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
- `%Y`     Year, numeric, four digits

Comment: How will this convert the (abbreviated) month names to Icelandic? Des instead of Dec for instance.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that is why I asked for a clarification to OP in comments.  There is no response yet. I am not aware that shortform of Dec is Des in icelandic.

Comment: Well OP wrote that it should be in Icelandic and even gave an example. Why did you believe something that is different is an error?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much the same as the answer in the link I used when voting to close this as a duplicate

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is not an exact duplicate. OP was using wrong format specifier as well.